# Debug the "NaN" error of sklearn using pandas dataframe input

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I read my input as pandas dataframe and filled NaN by:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
```

After that I split into train and test set and do a classification using sklearn.

```
features = df.drop('class',axis=1)
labels = df['class']
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
```

But I still got an error

> "NaN error": ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

It seems that `fillna()` didn't find the missing data. How can I find where the "NaN" is?

Comment: "infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')" Have you checked those two cases too?

Comment: features.dtypes shows that columns' type are int64 and float64, for infinity, no, I didn't

Comment: Do any of your features contain strings?  I do not think dropna will consider them NaN

Comment: the data is generate by a feature calculation tools, so they are all numeric features. But if any features contain strings, I can find it using  
features.dtypes, right?

Comment: You can try to impute the data with the `imputer` class, go to the docs!.

Comment: What do you get when you do `df.info()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

that can show you if/where any NaN's exist inside the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: pip install pandas --upgrade

Came across this issue myself today.  Seemed to be an issue with sklearn's train_test_split() method when dealing with sparse arrays with all zeros.  I raised a bug on scikit-learns github repo to which they very promptly responded with the solution of upgrading pandas:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22133

**Steps/Code to repoduce**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(sparse.eye(5))
y = pd.Series(np.zeros(5))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
# output as expected (when every input column has at least one non zero value)
print(X_train)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X[1:], y[1:], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
# output column contains all NaN (when input column contains all zero's)
print(X_train)
```

The first train_test_split() outputs as expected as every column has at least one non zero row, however the second outputs NaN's on the first column as all rows are zero.

```
    0    1    2    3    4
 --------------------------
 4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 2  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0

   0    1    2    3    4
 -------------------------
 4 NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 1 NaN  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 3 NaN  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You ask

> How can I find where the "NaN" is

Would it be helpful to visualize where the problematic data lie in the frame?

You could try `matplotlib.pyplot.spy`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# lets make some initial clean data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'alpha': [0, 1, 2],
        'beta': [3, 4, 5],
        'gamma': [6, 7, 8]
    },
    index=['one', 'two', 'three']
)
# add some problematic points
# `NaN`s, infinities and stuff that is 
#  just not numeric
df.loc['one', 'beta'] = 'not a number but not NaN'
df.loc['two', 'alpha'] = np.NaN
df.loc['three', 'gamma'] = np.infty

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)
axes[0].spy(df.isnull())
axes[0].set_title('NaN elements')
axes[1].spy(df == np.infty)
axes[1].set_title('infinite elements')
axes[2].spy(~df.applymap(np.isreal))
axes[2].set_title('Non numeric elements')
```